# Simplifying a generalized formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is from a computer networking problem, but a background in networking is not required for this formula to be simplified.

We're asked to calculate the average queuing delay for $N$ packets, where the queuing delay is $0$ for the first packet, $\tfrac{L}{R}$ for the second transmitted packet, $2 \tfrac{L}{R}$ for the second packet,
and generally, $(N-1) \tfrac{L}{R}$ for the $N$th transmitted packet.

Thus, the average delay for the $N$ packets is:

\begin{gather}
a = \frac{\left( \tfrac{L}{R} + 2 \tfrac{L}{R} + \cdots + (N-1) \tfrac{L}{R} \right)}{N}, \\[2mm]
a = \frac{(N-1)L}{2R}. 
\end{gather}

Here's my question: how exactly do we get from step 1, $\tfrac{(L/R + 2L/R + \cdots + (N-1)L/R)}{N}$, to the final formula, $\frac{(N-1)L}{2R}$? A detailed explanation of the steps in between would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's not much detail to give. Factor out the common factor of $L/R$, and then apply the result that $1+2+\cdots+n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Comment: Sorry, my math is a bit rusty. Took me a while to visualize this in my head and go through it step by step. Yes, factoring out L/R from the dividend portion of the equation to give us L/R(1 + 2  + ... + (N-1)) seems to be the first step, and then everything follows from there. The other key piece of info I was missing was that 1 + 2 + ... + N = N(N+1)/2.